# ng-bootstrap modal dialog in Angular - getting closeResult value before continuing execution

Tags: angular, modal-dialog, twitter-bootstrap-4, ng-bootstrap

I'm working on an Angular project (currently version 5), and making use of ng-bootstrap.

I've followed the ng-bootstrap documentation, and with some modifications have a modal component working that I can call from multiple components, passing in a unique title and message each time.

When the modal closes, I get the closeResult back via the {{confirmationModal.closeResult}} on the component, but I can't get it back in code in time to branch execution based on the result. The value is available in my method for the previous closeResult if I open the modal again, but not the current result.

My intent is to use this as a confirmation Modal for things like 'Are you sure you want to delete this?' etc.

See this Plunkr here: http://plnkr.co/edit/4thFjHietATRYn6g24ie?p=preview

You can see in the logged output, the first closeResult is undefined, as the code in the function continues to execute while the modal is visible. When the Modal is called again, the previous closeResult is logged out.

```
[Log] this.confirmationModal.closeResult – undefined
[Log] this.confirmationModal.closeResult – "Dismissed with: Cancel"
[Log] this.confirmationModal.closeResult – "Closed with: Ok"
[Log] this.confirmationModal.closeResult – "Dismissed with: Cancel"
[Log] this.confirmationModal.closeResult – "Dismissed with: Cross click"
```

I want the code to wait for a result before executing, and I'm not sure if I should be following the modal with a loop until the closeResult value is set, however that doesn't seem like the right way to handle this.

I would have expected the Modal to suspend code execution and return the closeResult when the dialog is dismissed, or make the closeResult available as an Observable, but I can't quite seem to make it work the way I need/expect it to.

The following code is in the Plunkr, and it's a modified version of the code used in my project based on the ng-bootstrap example Plunkr.

My modal-basic.ts file:

```
import {Component, Input, ViewChild} from '@angular/core';

import {NgbModal, ModalDismissReasons} from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';

@Component({
  selector: 'ngbd-modal-basic',
  templateUrl: 'src/modal-basic.html'
})
export class NgbdModalBasic {
    @Input()
    title

    @Input() 
    message;

    @ViewChild('content') content: any;

  closeResult: string;

  constructor(private modalService: NgbModal) {}

  open(content) {
    this.modalService.open(this.content).result.then((result) => {
      this.closeResult = `Closed with: ${result}`;
    }, (reason) => {
      this.closeResult = `Dismissed ${this.getDismissReason(reason)}`;
    });
  }

  private getDismissReason(reason: any): string {
    if (reason === ModalDismissReasons.ESC) {
      return 'by pressing ESC';
    } else if (reason === ModalDismissReasons.BACKDROP_CLICK) {
      return 'by clicking on a backdrop';
    } else {
      return  `with: ${reason}`;
    }
  }
}
```

modal-basic.html file:

```
 <ng-template #content let-c="close" let-d="dismiss">
        <div class="modal-header">
        <h4 class="modal-title">{{title}}</h4>
        <button type="button" class="close" aria-label="Close" (click)="d('Cross click')">
            <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
        <p>{{message}}</p>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-dark" (click)="d('Cancel')">Cancel</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-dark" (click)="c('Ok')">Ok</button>
        </div>
    </ng-template>
```

app.ts file:

```
import { Component, NgModule, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';
import { NgbModule } from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';
import { NgbdModalBasic } from './modal-basic';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
    <div class="container-fluid">

    <hr>
    <p>
      This is a demo plnkr forked from the <strong>ng-bootstrap</strong> project: Angular powered Bootstrap.
      Visit <a href="https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/" target="_blank">https://ng-bootstrap.github.io</a> for more widgets and demos.
    </p>
    <hr>

<button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-dark" (click)="openModal()">Open Modal</button>

    <ngbd-modal-basic [message]='message' [title]='title' #confirmationModal></ngbd-modal-basic>{{confirmationModal.closeResult}}
  </div>
  `
})
export class App {

    title: string;
  message: string;

  @ViewChild('confirmationModal') confirmationModal: NgbdModalBasic;

 openModal() {
    this.title = "Title of the Modal";
    this.message = "Modal message.";

    this.confirmationModal.open();

    console.log("this.confirmationModal.closeResult", this.confirmationModal.closeResult);
 }
}   

@NgModule({
  imports: [BrowserModule, FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule, HttpClientModule, NgbModule.forRoot()], 
  declarations: [App, NgbdModalBasic]
  bootstrap: [App]
}) 
export class AppModule {}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can use @Output, so, in your ngb-modal-basic

```
@Output() close: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter();
...
open(content) {
    this.modalService.open(this.content).result.then((result) => {
      this.closeResult = `Closed with: ${result}`;
      this.close.emit(result); //<---return the result
    }, (reason) => {
      this.closeResult = `Dismissed ${this.getDismissReason(reason)}`;
      this.close.emit(result); //<---return the result
    });
  }
```

You can use in your component:

```
<ngbd-modal-basic [message]='message' [title]='title' #confirmationModal (close)="close(result)"></ngbd-modal-basic>
... and
close(result)
{
   console.log(result)
}
```